# combining video and audio using ffmpeg not working

Tags: python, ffmpeg

hi im trying to merge an av1 encoded video and a mp4 audio file but when i run the program cmd pops up for a bit and then disappears and in the end nothing happens aside from done being printed.

```
import ffmpeg

input_video = ffmpeg.input('C:\\Users\\meep0\\Documents\\Programming\\trouble.mp4')
input_audio = ffmpeg.input("C:\\Users\\meep0\\Documents\\Programming\\trouble audio.mp3")
ffmpeg.concat(input_video, input_audio, v=1, a=1).output("C:\\Users\\meep0\\Documents\\Programming").run()

print("done")
```